# Как элемент массива nums1[3] получил значение 99

Tags: java, массивы

Изучаю массивы. Подскажите пожалуйста - не пойму момент с присваиванием.
Вот мы в определенный момент видим, что `nums2 = nums1`; a затем мы делаем `nums2[3] = 99`; и при выводе в консоль мы видим, что значение аналогичного элемента изменилось и в массиве `nums[1]`. Как так? Мы же не делали `nums1=nums2`...

Объясните популярно пожалуйста - как так получилось...

```
public class Massive8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;

        int nums1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        int nums2[] = {0, -1, -2, -3, -4};

        System.out.print("Массив nums1: ");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.print(nums1[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Массив nums2: ");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.print(nums2[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        nums2 = nums1;

        System.out.print("Массив nums2 после присваивания: ");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.print(nums2[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

        nums2[3] = 99;

        System.out.print("Массив nums1 после изменения через nums2: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.print(nums1[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Рекомендую вам почитать про разницу между тип ссылка и тип значение

Comment: Таким образом ты ссылаешься с одного массива на другой, и при изменении в одном меняется и второй.

Comment: Спасибо. Полезное замечание - почитал - все прояснилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java массивы реализованы как объекты, т.е они передаются по ссылке, а не по значению.  В данном случае, Вы передайте переменной nums2 ссылку на переменную nums1. Т.е. понятным языком, и nums1 и nums2 ссылаются на одну и ту же ячейку памяти, на один и тот же массив. Именно поэтому при nums2[3]=99, и nums1[3] будет равен 99. Если же Вы хотите присвоить значение конкретному индексу/порядковому номеру какого либо массива, то: nums1[i]=nums2[i], где I конкретный индекс/порядковый номер массива.